# Equivalent of python ElementTree.write() in perl with libxml?

Tags: python, python-3.x, perl, libxml2

With python I would use the [ElementTree.write](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.ElementTree.write) method:

```py
tree.write("myfile", method="text")
```

So from this xml:

```xml
<all>
<a>ABC<b><s> </s>GHJK</b></a>
<z>1234</z>
</all>
```

I would get:

```
ABC GHJK
1234
```

But I couldn't find something similar in the cpan libxml documentation.
Is there something similar for perl's libxml ?

Comment: Using [XML::LibXML](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::LibXML)?

Comment: Yes. I must use it to work on the XML, so it would be nice to not have to use another library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for the [`textContent` method of `XML::LibXML::Node`](https://metacpan.org/dist/XML-LibXML/view/lib/XML/LibXML/Node.pod#textContent):

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use XML::LibXML;

my $dom = XML::LibXML->load_xml(IO => *DATA);
my $root = $dom->documentElement;
print $root->textContent;

__DATA__
<all>
<a>ABC<b><s> </s>GHJK</b></a>
<z>1234</z>
</all>
```

prints out

```
ABC GHJK
1234
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I feel silly for not seeing that method in the documentation.